# What is the purpose of all the *.msp files in the Windows installer folder?

Tags: windows-10

What is the purpose of all the `*.msp` files in the Windows installer folder?

The C:\ Drive is huge. It has grown to over 90GB. I did a disk analysis and 25GB are in the Installer folder alone. I use Glary Utilities and Avira Antivirus Utility, in addition to Windows Disk Clean-up. Something seems wrong. I also ran Spybot Search and Destroy.

I'm wondering if I can just clear out some of the `.msp` files myself?

Comment: Can you provide specifics?

Comment: Yes, they *can* be removed, but it is not safe to do so manually. See https://superuser.com/questions/835026/can-i-safely-remove-msi-and-msp-files-that-are-in-c-windows-installer-but-a and https://whatsoftware.com/safely-delete-unused-msi-and-mst-files-from-windows-installer-folder/ . If you need room, also clean up the WinSxS folder: https://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/

Comment: Found PatchCleaner v1.4.2.0 tool. Deleted 204 orphaned files = 15 Gb. How do I clean WinSxS?